# ggplot Stacked Bars No Values Just Counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
       set.seed(1)
     data = data.frame("ID" = (1:1000),
  "S1"=sample(1:5, r=T,1000),
                "S2"=c(sample(1:5, r=T,990), rep(NA,10)),
                "S3"=c(sample(1:5, r=T,990), rep(NA,10)),
                "S4"=c(sample(1:5, r=T,990), rep(NA,10)),
                "S5"=c(sample(1:5, r=T,995), rep(NA,5)),
                "S6"=sample(1:5, r=T,1000),
                "S7"=sample(1:5, r=T,1000),
                "S8"=sample(1:5, r=T,1000),
                "S9"=sample(1:5, r=T,1000),
                "S10"=sample(1:5, r=T,1000))
```

data1 = melt(data,id.vars="id")
attempt,

```
ggplot(data1, aes(fill=value, y=sum(value), x=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

These are my data. I am wishing to generate a bag graph such as:

[image]

Where the X axis is the numeric value from the column names on data, and the colors equal to the values (1 always on bottom in red, 2 in orange always in middle and 3 in yellow always the top) and the actual height of each bar is the sum of values in each S variable. So for example at 1 shown in figure, the height of the red bar is the number of '1' values in 'S1'

Answer (score 1):

`geom_bar` by default use `stat = "count"` function from `ggplot2`, so it will count the number of values for x. Combined with a filling category, it will count the number of values of each x combined with each filling (here, 1,2,3,4...).

Here, I used `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` package to reshape your dataframe into a longer format more suitable with `ggplot2` grammar. I filtered out `NA` in order to get the real count without NA values.

Also, I used `position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` in `geom_bar` to get the right ordering of your color pattern.

Altogether, it gives you:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "X", values_to = "Val") %>%
  mutate(X = factor(X, unique(X))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Val)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, fill = factor(Val)))+
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a bunch that is really great. how can I handle the spaces on the bottom of s2-s4? for example i just want the earlier bars to be lower because they have fewer values. in other words i do not want to include NA in the figure I just want to show that there are more later on as indicated by the number of real values

Comment: You're welcome, I edited my answer according to your question.